# Case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: android, android-intent

Этот кусок кода:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Переписала, что бы запускался и на ранних версиях, но с ошибкой. Подскажите, что я сделала не так:

```
int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_websearch){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            } else if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivity(intent);              
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Ошибка тут:

```
else if (intent.resolveActivity ...
```

Ошибка: intent cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я мимопроходил и не сильно разбирался что происходит, но бросается в глаза, что Вы не просто заменили case на if, а также изменили вложенность условных операторов. Так задумано?

Ну я к тому что блок

```
case{  
  block1  
  if {block2}
  else {block3}
}
```

и блок:

```
if{block1}
else if {block2}
else {block3}
```

Ни разу не эквивалентны. Вы пытаетесь использовать intent в условии для блока два, объявив его в блоке 1, куда программа не заходит.

Comment: @Volt По идее да.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал [[@Volt](/users/17812/volt)](/users/17812/volt), у Вас условия неправильно переведены, должен быть вложенный if:

```
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_websearch){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(intent);              
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;
} else {     
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```